# How to Calculate Median EWM in Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, median, weighted-average

Pandas does not have the option to calculate Median EWM for a timeseries DataFrame. Does anyone have a work around?

```
df.ewm().mean()    # This function exists in Pandas
df.ewm().std()     # This function exists in Pandas
df.ewm().median()  # Doesn't exist. Looking to replicate this capability
```

Answer (score -3):

Can you use numpy?

```
import numpy as np

np.median(df.ewm())
```

As of pandas 1.2.3 the docs are clear that only the following EW functions are available:

```
Available EW functions: ``mean()``, ``var()``, ``std()``, ``corr()``, ``cov()``.
```

Comment: getting the following error: 
`{TypeError}unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'ExponentialMovingWindow' and 'int'`

Comment: I'm haven't previously used the exponentially weighted operations provided by pandas for what it's worth (sorry that I didn't check the proposed answer first). Clearly the `df.emw()` returns a more complex object than a simple array, which is what `np.median()` expects and why you are getting that error. Thinking about it more, it might be that computing a weighted median doesn't really make sense mathematically, but this is a bit out of my wheelhouse :)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm thinking of this problem as more of a "sampling with replacement" problem where the likelihood of the sample being chosen decreases exponentially back through time. Then if we bootstrap this distribution, we can then calculate the median... that would be my brute force approach to this problem.

Comment: Interesting. Again, not being super familiar with the math behind the  exponential weighting functions, but to follow through with your idea, maybe you can use the EMW functions to generate probabilities for each datapoint and add that column to your dataframe. Then you can use something like:
`df['sampling_weights'] = <apply exp func here>`; 
`weighted_sample = df.sample(<num_samples>, replace=True, weights=df['sampling_weights'])`; 
`weighted_sample.median()`